# Vuedraggle is dragged into the specified column, and the name of the group is different. What is the reason?

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

Vuedraggle is dragged into the specified column, and the name of the group is different. What is the reason?I want to drag from the a list to the specified column, such as c, d
How to implement this function? The official website says that the group can be specified with the same name, but I am different now, and I can drag it.

I want to drag from the a list to the specified column, such as c, d

Comment: we need code example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.